# Converting Negative Decimal To String Loses the -

Tags: c#

I'm required to send in a negative myDecimalValue.ToString("C");  The problem is if myDecimalValue is a negative, lets say -39, after conversion I'm getting $39.00 as the string not $39.00.  So I'm not sure how to go about this.

This is the utility method that takes in the decimal.  If the decimal is negative, I want the ToString to show a negative

```
    public static BasicAmountType CreateBasicAmount(string amount, CurrencyCodeType currencyType)
    {
        BasicAmountType basicAmount = new BasicAmountType
                                          {
                                              currencyID = currencyType,
                                              Value = amount
                                          };
        return basicAmount;
    }
```

I could go either way, a C or F2, all I care is about getting that negative sign intothe string if the incoming decimal is negative.  I suppose there's no way to do this unless I check for negativity inside my utility method here.  I can't just send a negative number and expect the ToString to work and for the ToSTring to automatically see that the decimal is negative incoming?

Comment: *I'm getting $39.00 as the string not $39.00.* — So zen.

Comment: He is referring to the fact that in your question, the expected result is the same as what you are getting ($39.00 not $39.00); when you probably meant "...getting $39.00 as the string not $-39.00."

Comment: The simple solution is string s = String.Format("${0:0.00}", myDecimalValue);.  This whole NumberFormatInfo stuff is way, way overkill and to me probably looks inefficient because you're creating all these objects just to format this thing.  Plus not to mention 2+ lines of code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
decimal myDecimalValue = -39m;
string s = String.Format("${0:0.00}", myDecimalValue); // $-39.00
```

However, SLaks is right, negative values are usually shown in parenthesis.

Comment: this is all I had to do, simple as that.

Answer (score 8):

This should work for you:

```
decimal num = -39M;
NumberFormatInfo currencyFormat = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString()).NumberFormat;
currencyFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(currencyFormat, "{0:c}", num));  // -$39.00
```

Comment: Good God!  So that's how you use NumberFormatInfo. That's nuts!  What about jYelton's solution, much simpler...???

Comment: JYelton's is good if you're always going to be displaying dollars.  Which may be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Negative currencies are represented by parentheses, not minus signs: `($39.00)`.

This is controlled by the `NumberFormatInfo` of the `CultureInfo` that you pass to `ToString`.

Comment: You see parentheses in finance, but Joe Sixpack doesn't see that on the web.  Think of seeing a discount for an online purchase.

Answer (score 1):

From ["Standard Numeric Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

> ...The default for InvariantInfo  is 0,
>   which represents "($n)", where "$" is
>   the CurrencySymbol  and n is a number.

So you can call ToString(IFormatProvider) instead of ToString(), passing a NumberFormatInfo on which you set [CurrencyNegativePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) = 1;

```
     decimal d = -39M;
     NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
     nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$"; // didn't default to "$" for me.
     nfi.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
     string s = d.ToString("C", nfi); // -$39.00
```

Comment: @Forgotten gives a more robust and polite way to do it by taking the current culture into account when creating the NumberFormatInfo. Mine just brute forces it in.

Comment: The CurrencySymbol didn't default to '$' because the NumberFormatInfo needs a CultureInfo. (Was commenting at the same time, JeffH.  I like your links though).

Comment: You're right.  What I should have said was that the NumberFormatInfo is usually gleaned from an instance CultureInfo (like CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).