# Format decimal with positive negative and zero value to 2 decimal places format

Tags: c#, .net

I have a parameter price which is of type decimal it can have a positive, negative and zero value. The value will never have a decimal but needs to display a decimal.

While I parse the decimal it does handle 0 and > 0 values but does not handle negative values. How can I handle all 3 in one parse operation?

```
decimal.Parse(a.price.ToString("##.00"), NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
```

I need to convert the data to show in European culture so value of -3.00 should show up as -3,00.

Here is what I am trying and it gives me an exception

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL");
Price = a.GroupId == g ? decimal.Parse(a.BidPrice.ToString("##.000",  culture), NumberStyles.Number) : decimal.Parse(decimal.Zero.ToString("##.000",  culture), NumberStyles.Number)
```

A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Adding some test data,

```
3 should show up as 3,00
-3 should show up as -3,00
0 should show up as 0,00
```

**Edit**
The default culture is en-GB

Comment: This seems strange.. you have decimal, and you do "ToStirng" on it, just to parse it back to decimal? What do you wan't to achive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569166/converting-negative-decimal-to-string-loses-the

Comment: As strange as life is my friend, I need the decimal to carry decimals, that's the way the system I am passing the data on to accepts the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `NumberStyles.Number`, that'll work:

```
decimal price = -3;
decimal result = decimal.Parse(price.ToString("##.00"), NumberStyles.Number);
//Result: -3,00 (comma because I live in Europe :D)
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

To ensure a comma use the German CultureInfo as they use a comma for a decimal and the period as the thousand separator:

```
decimal price = -3;
decimal result = decimal.Parse(price.ToString("##.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")), NumberStyles.Number);
```

Comment: What if I actually wanted a comma instead of a decimal? What format would i use in that case?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. It gives me an exception "A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". See the updated question on what I am trying to do.

Comment: What does the Exception say?

Comment: Another problem. With this format, the number -350 is showing as -350000. I would expect -350,00 (where , is the decimal separator as per the de-DE culture).

Comment: What is your default CultureInfo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32823/discussion-between-tarun-arora-and-abbas)